# millisecond and microsecond information not exported when writing datetime to Excel

Tags: python, excel, datetime, openpyxl

While export datetime data from a TDMS file to an Excel spreadsheet using openpyxl, millisecond and microsecond information disappears.

Using openpyxl on Python 3.7. The datetime pulled from the TDMS file contains time which includes microseconds, for example here is output from printing the value and style of a variable containing one of these datetime objects:
2018-02-05 14:30:13.290399+00:00

When exported to Excel, the portion after seconds disappears:
2018-02-05 14:30:13

I tried using NamedStyle, but I couldn't find how to define milli- or microseconds using this tool.

```
from nptdms import TdmsFile
from openpyxl import Workbook

# Writing channel data to Excel spreadsheet 
wb = Workbook()
wfilename = 'channel_data.xlsx'
ws1 = wb.active
ws1.title = 'Full Data'

# a is a list of datetime objects pulled from a TDMS file
b = a[0]
print(b)
# output is:
# 2018-02-05 14:30:13.290399+00:00

t = type(b)
print(t)
# output is:
# <class 'datetime.datetime'>

ws1.cell(row=1, column=1).value=b
wfilepath = [somefilepath]
wb.save(wfilepath)
```

In the resulting Excel file, the cell contains the following:
2018-02-05 14:30:13

This is missing all info after seconds. Can anyone see why this is happening?

EDIT:
I was able to convert to string using the following code:

```
w = b.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
print(w)
```

and get the following output in Excel in a 'General' format cell:
2018/02/05 14:30:13:290399

I would still like to be able to export this as datetime instead of having to convert to string.

Comment: Bring it in as a string then parse it to the correct format... Otherwise you loose bits..

Comment: I'd strongly advise against XLSX for sensitive datetimes, the format really isn't suitable and demonstrably error prone but openpyxl does at least allow you to save them iso format.

Comment: alright. I will stick with exporting as strings. this is primarily for reporting purposes anyway. I'll export an additional column for time elapsed, also as strings.